# Auto Populating the next number in line VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below VBA which is populating the next number in the line. But it has an issue I keep getting an error when it is automatically populating the next number down. The data is in a table and the error I get is:

The table starts with one line on row 2. I enter the data in H2 it populates just fine but an error shows, I do the same for row 3 and again fine. Then I do row 4 and the formula then starts to copy row 3's value and then I enter row 5 and it copies row 3's value. The error I get in I3 is

> formula refers to an empty cell

I traced it and it's saying H2 is empty (it is not).

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range([H2], Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)))

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cel In rng.Offset(, 1)
        cel.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & _
            "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Can someone help to fix the error?

thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. If I use your code and start to enter data in column H downwards it starts writing `-0001-`, `-0002-` and so on in column I. I cannot produce an error in these formulas, even if I empty H2 it just removes the counting number from I2 and starts counting from I3 instead.

Comment: Note that instead of your entire `For Each` loop you can do this in one step by using `rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"`

Comment: thank you for checking and providing the update. i have now noticed the code works outside tables. as soon as i put it into a table it does the above. thank you for looking into it!

Comment: In a "table" you'll have to amend your code to work against the Range inside the ListObject.